# linux kernel when is file descriptor not accessible by pread?

Tags: linux, kernel, vfs

so I am reading some kernel code and notice this:
http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/fs.h?v=2.6.32#L63

in line 69, we have:

```
  /* file can be accessed using pread */
  #define FMODE_PREAD             ((__force fmode_t)8)
```

I am wondering when would a fd be not accessible by pread? I thought we can do pread on any fd...

Thanks!

Erben

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`man pread` on my Linux system says:

```
The file referenced by fd must be capable of seeking.
```

So if a file descriptor is not seekable (e.g. a socket or stdin), you will not be able to `pread` it.

Comment: awesome... I was trying to figure out why the fd I created is not accessible to pread. Turns out the fd equals 0. Hence I asked this stupid question.